# Bump Node bumps pixels of image

Tags: node-editor, image, bump

[image]

You see my problem above? How can I solve this? Does the Image texture maybe need to be a higher resolution?

Comment: Hello, maybe tell if this helps? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203314/bump-map-appears-pixelated

Answer (score 3):

These are most likely compression artifacts of the image itself:
[image]
Happens often with jpeg images. You could try to get a higher resolution and/or a higher bitrate format like PNG.

Alternatively, you could throw in a color ramp and tweak the white and black sliders until the artifacts are gone:
[image]
But this won't get you a higher resolution, obviously.

**NOTE: For bump maps, always set the *Color Space* of the image texture to "Non-Color Data"!**

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped!