# How do I change the funny bake results?

Tags: texturing, materials

I use Translation.
When baked, it has a strange unevenness.
The original bake is smooth.
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Left High polygon
Right Low polygon

Trying to erase the material does not change the result.

Comment: Your image needs to be PNG 16-Bit or 32-Bit Float, but you need to re-bake, a simple conversion of your current image won't work

Comment: I asked the same question here, please tell if it fixes your problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203314/bump-map-appears-pixelated

Comment: Thank you very much!
The work has progressed as if the stagnation of a while ago was a lie!
Thank you so much!