# bump map is pixelated?

Tags: uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor, shader-nodes, bump

I'm trying to make a bump map for this but it looks pixelated.

pic of the object:

[image]
pic of the shader nodes:

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the image is 16 or 32 bit-float PNG, check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203314/bump-map-appears-pixelated or maybe your b&w image is pixelated